# Why isn't my IIS Rewrite rule working for images?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have some code that points to this URL that doesn't exist:

```
http://www.newradicals.com/movies/(500) Days of Summer (2009)/folder.jpg
```

I want it to rewrite to this URL:

```
http://www.newradicals.com/movies/(500) Days of Summer (2009)-poster.jpg
```

I have the following rule set up but it's not working at all. When I go to the image URL in the browser, nothing happens, I still get a 404.

Match URL (matches pattern, regular expression):

```
^([^]+)/movies/([^]+)/folder.jpg
```

Rewrite to:

```
movies/{R:2}-poster.jpg
```

Anyone know why this isn't working and what I need to do to fix it?

Comment: In URL, we rarely use filename / path with spaces, mix-case letters, and symbols. Reconsider it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...

I found that I needed to just change the pattern to remove the domain:

```
^movies/([^]+)/folder.jpg
```

and then slightly modify the rewrite:

```
movies/{R:1}-poster.jpg
```